# Accurate way of finding out number of times a file has been download

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a download page with a `linkbutton` that users use to download files. The event handler of the `linkbutton` sets up the Response type for the user to see the download dialog and chose to save it. I need to find out accurately how many times the file has been downloaded. If I increment a counter in the link button's event handler, I'd assume it wouldn't be accurate as the user may chose to click on Cancel in the download dialog.

Where exactly do I need to hook this counter incrementing logic?

Answer (score 4):

You may write a HttpHandler which sends the file.

After the sending has finished then you can increment the number of downloads

Comment: I havent written HttpHandlers before. Can you please elaborate how to do this?

Comment: I think you should do sth similar to this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686540/sending-file-in-chunks-to-httphandler

Answer (score 0):

Route your file through a 2nd .aspx file that simply reads the real file from disk and echoes it to the page, then when it's done, increment the download counter in your database.

Comment: Use HttpResponse.TransmitFile instead of HttpResponse.SendFile - the latter uses a lot of memory, if the file is large!

Comment: Do I "have" to transmit files as chunks if the files are large?

Comment: Probably, yes. Unless you know for sure the files are small, in which case it doesn't really matter if you buffer them or not.